# MySQL SELECT id of row where GREATEST of MAX entries of several columns

Tags: mysql, select, max, multiple-columns

I have this table mytable:

```
+----+--------------------------------------+
| id | date1      | date2      | date3      |
+----+--------------------------------------+
| 1  | 2014-01-08 | NULL       | NULL       | 
| 2  | 2014-05-09 | NULL       | NULL       | 
| 3  | 2014-06-13 | NULL       | NULL       | 
| 4  | NULL       | 2014-03-24 | NULL       | 
| 2  | NULL       | NULL       | 2014-08-15 | 
| 4  | 2014-01-01 | NULL       | NULL       | 
| 1  | 2014-02-15 | NULL       | NULL       | 
| 3  | NULL       | 2014-12-06 | 2014-10-12 | 
| 4  | 2014-08-06 | NULL       | NULL       | 
| 2  | 2014-05-22 | NULL       | NULL       | 
+----+--------------------------------------+
```

Now I try to have one SELECT with the following result:

```
  id   max_date1    max_date2    max_date3
---------------------------------------------
| 3  | 2014-08-06 | 2014-12-06 | 2014-10-12 |
```

That means the MAX of each date column and the ID from the row in which the GREATEST of the MAX results is.

The Query, that brought me nearly to the solution looks like this:

```
SELECT
   id, max(date1), max(date2), max(date3), GREATEST(
     IFNULL(max(date1), 0),
     IFNULL(max(date2), 0),
     IFNULL(max(date3), 0)) AS maxdate
FROM table1
```

But the id i get, is not the expected one. How can I find out which column has the maxdate so I can find out the appendant id?

[see fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/123f9/6).

Comment: have you tried sub query? may be that should work

Comment: well, I tried a lot, subqueries too. But you have to know that I am an absolute SQL beginner :)

Comment: you have many answers from experts.... hope you are able to solve your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a way to do it would be to store your date in a user-defined-variable. then you can use it to pull out the id for the largest date

```
SET @A := (SELECT GREATEST(
                     IFNULL(max(date1), 0),
                     IFNULL(max(date2), 0),
                     IFNULL(max(date3), 0)
                  ) FROM table1
           );
-- here i JOIN a select that pulls out the correct id
SELECT t.joinid, max(`date1`), max(`date2`), max(`date3`)
FROM table1
JOIN 
(   SELECT id as joinid 
    FROM table1
    WHERE @A IN -- WHERE my MAX date is in
    (
        SELECT date1 -- here the UNION is just putting all of the dates into one column to compare one date with
        UNION ALL SELECT date2
        UNION ALL SELECT date3
    )
) t -- every table must have an alias
```

[FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/123f9/21)

Comment: Hey guy, you rock! You seem to be an SQL freak. The query brings the solution for me, although I still hope to find an easyer way...

Comment: @MaggusK thanks, I've only learned what I know from being on here :)

Comment: Nevertheless I would like to understand this query better. It's clear about the variable. I have to read about UNION. But what about 'temp'? Is this a table temporarily made by the syntax?

Comment: @MaggusK temp is just an alias that is required... when you do a select with JOIN's it is returning a table... a temporary table created in memory that is displayed and goes away when you do the select... it isn't actually creating a `TEMPORARY TABLE` that MySQL supports..

Comment: @MaggusK I just edited providing some explanation of the query. the main thing to remember is this. when you SELECT something.. what you see returned is a table that gets built. you can use a TEMPORARY TABLE that is creating a temporary table from which you can do a SELECT from.. but that goes away after your session (how long you have the window open for your IDE).. thats why the alias is needed for the table because you have to be able to call it something.. notice `SELECT t.joinid, ` it is a way to specify which column you are pulling out from where

Comment: @MaggusK of course! if you have any more questions or anything I'll be more than happy to help :) +1 reciprocated for you

Answer (score 0):

please note that when you use MAX,MIN,etc in query, you are practically loosing connection between that value and others. This solution down there may be a bit different, then what you expected, but it simply finds greatest values of 3 fields and the compares them as rows.

```
(select id,'date1' as col,(date1) as d from table1 order by d desc limit 1)
UNION
(select id,'date2' as col,(date2) as d from table1 order by d desc limit 1) 
UNION
(select id,'date3' as col,(date3) as d from table1 order by d desc limit 1)
ORDER BY d desc
```

Comment: Thank you David. Not THE solution for me, but you brought me further with understanding sql :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 

  (
  CASE
   WHEN max(t1.date1) >= max(t2.date2) && max(t1.date1) >= max(t3.date3) THEN
    t1.id
   WHEN max(t2.date2) >= max(t1.date1) && max(t2.date2) >= max(t3.date3) THEN
    t2.id
   ELSE
    t3.id
  END) AS  highest_data_row_id,
  max(t1.date1),
  max(t2.date2),
  max(t3.date3)

FROM
  table1 t1, table1 t2, table1 t3
```

Comment: Hey Andrzej, this looks logical for me, but sadly throws an syntax error (at least in SQL Fiddle). Also if I renamed the 'table' into 'table1' in last query row :(

Comment: I fixed it for you.. were missing a comma after `highest_data_row_id`

Comment: Thanx. As I just recognized it's not possible to mark more than one answer as solution...

Comment: but You can + John's answer too. It looks ok.

Comment: @AndrzejReduta [**SEE FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/123f9/26) this is not returning the desired results as the id is 1 and not 3

Comment: While I inspect the code I think this can not work because all three cases will propably give the same result. There is no difference between t1, t2 and t3

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    id, max(date1), max(date2), max(date3), GREATEST(
     IFNULL(max(date1), 0),
     IFNULL(max(date2), 0),
     IFNULL(max(date3), 0)) AS maxdate,
     ( select id from 
     (
        select id, max(date1) as temp from table1 group by 1
        union
        select id, max(date2) as temp from table1 group by 1
        union
        select id, max(date3) as temp from table1 group by 1
     ) temptable order by temp desc limit 1) as ok_id
FROM table1;
```

Comment: this isn't recommended because its using a correlated subquery and then a subquery with that that is selecting everything from the table 3 times.. the overhead on this is going to be massive

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/e4f3f/2

```
 SELECT id, max(date1) As max_date1, max(date2) As max_date2, max(date3) As max_date3 FROM table1 GROUP BY id
```