# MySQL UNION SELECT on several columns to find MAX of MAX

Tags: mysql, select, max, union

This is a continuation of my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26738338).

Assume we have three tables. A main table and two id tables.

```
+-----+-----+--------------------------------------+
| cid | pid | date1      | date2      | date3      |
+-----+-----+--------------------------------------+
|  1  |  2  | NULL       | 2014-03-24 | 2014-03-24 | 
|  3  |  1  | 2014-06-13 | NULL       | NULL       | 
|  4  |  3  | NULL       | 2014-09-14 | NULL       | 
|  2  |  1  | NULL       | NULL       | 2014-08-15 | 
|  4  |  3  | 2014-01-10 | NULL       | NULL       | 
|  1  |  4  | 2014-02-15 | NULL       | NULL       | 
|  4  |  2  | NULL       | 2014-01-06 | 2014-01-12 | 
+-----+-----+------------+------------+------------+

+----+----------+     +----+--------+
| id | city     |     | id | person |
+----+----------+     +----+--------+
| 1  | 'Dallas' |     | 1  | 'John' |
| 2  | 'Berlin' |     | 2  | 'Jack' |
| 3  | 'Topeka' |     | 3  | 'Doug' |
| 4  | 'London' |     | 4  | 'Pete' |
+----+----------+     +----+--------+
```

Ok, now i'd like to make a select to get **one row per city** in the result. The row has to contain the city, the **max of each date** (date1, date2, date3) of this city and the person that belongs to the **max of the three max** dates.
Result:

```
+--------+--------+--------------------------------------+
| city   | person | date1      | date2      | date3      |
+--------+--------+--------------------------------------+
| Dallas | Jack   | 2014-02-15 | 2014-03-24 | 2014-03-24 | 
| Berlin | John   | NULL       | NULL       | 2014-08-15 | 
| Topeka | John   | 2014-06-13 | NULL       | NULL       | 
| London | Doug   | 2014-01-10 | 2014-09-14 | 2014-01-12 | 
+--------+--------+------------+------------+------------+
```

Mhh... I thought it would't be that difficult.

[see the fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d7c47/10)

Comment: Why are there 3 dates?

Comment: How do you get 2014-03-24 in date2 for Dallas in your expected result when all the rows for Dallas (cid = 1) in the main table have NULL in date2?

Comment: @Hans: you're right. Sorry,  complete wrong main table. Copy and paste error. I'll fix it...

Comment: ok Hans, it's fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I think this might work.

```
select c.city, p.person, y.date1, y.date2, y.date3
  from (select x.cid, x.date1, x.date2, x.date3, greatest(ifnull(x.date1, '0000-01-01'), ifnull(x.date2, '0000-01-01'), ifnull(x.date3, '0000-01-01')) as maxdate
          from (select cid, max(date1) as date1, max(date2) as date2, max(date3) as date3
                  from main
                 group by cid) as x)
              as y
join main m 
  on m.cid = y.cid and 
  (m.date1 = y.maxdate or m.date2 = y.maxdate or m.date3 = y.maxdate)
join city c 
  on y.cid = c.id
join person p 
  on m.pid = p.id
```

It starts by creating 'x' which is a table with the max dates for each city. Then it creates 'y' where it adds on the highest of the 3 dates. Then it joins with the main table to find the row for the city with the highest date. And then it joins the city and person table to get the names rather than the ids.

Comment: Well, it seemed to work first, but when I examined I found out, that it doesn't match the goal to have ONE ROW PER CITY! It only finds cities that have an item in the "main" table. Compare [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ac731/4) with [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c8358/1)