# Better database basis for table with multiple date informations

Tags: mysql, database-design

What do you think is the better basis, in sense of "easyer to use" with SQL Syntax - the first or the second table?
Please give reasons.

table one:

```
+----+--------------------------------------+
| id | date1      | date2      | date3      |
+----+------------+------------+------------+
| 1  | 2014-02-15 | 2014-03-24 | 2014-03-24 |
| 2  | NULL       | NULL       | 2014-08-15 |
| 3  | 2014-06-13 | NULL       | NULL       |
| 4  | 2014-01-10 | 2014-09-14 | 2014-01-12 |
+----+------------+------------+------------+
```

table two:

```
+----+------------+-------+-------+-------+
| id | date       | one   | two   | three |
+----+------------+-------+-------+-------+
| 1  | 2015-07-04 | true  | true  | false |
| 2  | 2014-06-13 | false | true  | false |
| 3  | 2014-11-11 | true  | false | false |
| 4  | 2017-03-02 | false | true  | true  |
+----+------------+-------+-------+-------+
```

(content of tables doesn't match in this example)

I just want to know if it is easier to deal with when you have just one date field and additional boolean fields instead of multiple date fields. For example if you want to have SELECTs like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26759441/mysql-union-select-on-several-columns-to-find-max-of-max)

Comment: These are both lousy designs.  You should have one row per date and flag.

Comment: cause there can be more than one boolean true, your idea does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends what the dates are.

Just because two fields are both dates tell us nothing about what they have to do with each other, if anything.

If the three dates are totally unrelated and would never be interchangeable in processing, and if they are a fixed set that is not likely to change frequently, like "birth date", "hire date", and "next annual review date", then I would just make them three separate fields. Then when you write queries it would be very straightforward, like

```
select employee_id, name from employee where next_annual_review_date='2015-02-01'
```

On the other hand, if you might quite reasonably write a query that would search all three dates, then it makes sense to break the dates out into another table, with a field that identifies the specific date. Like I created a table once for a warehouse system where there were many dates associated with a stock item -- the date it arrived in the warehouse, the date it was sold, inventoried, returned to the warehouse (because the customer returned it, for example), re-sold, lost, damaged, repaired, etc. These dates could come in many possible orders, and many of them could occur multiple times. Like an item might be damaged, repaired, and then damaged and repaired again, or it could be sold, returned, sold again, and returned again, etc. So I created a table for the stock item with the "static" info like part number, description, and the bazillion codes that the user needed to describe the item, and then a separate "stock event" table with the stock item id, event code, the date, and various other stuff. Then there was another stock event table that listed the event codes with descriptions.

This made it easy to construct queries like, "List everything that has happened to this item in the past four years in date order", or "list all items added to the inventory in November", etc.

Your second table seems like an all-around bad idea. I can't think of any advantage to having 3 Boolean fields rather than one field that says what it is. Suppose the three dates are birth date, hire date, and next review date. You could create codes for these -- maybe 1,2, 3; maybe B, H, R; whatever. Then selecting on a specific event is easy enough either way, I guess: select date where hire = true versus select date where event = 'H'.

But listing multiple dates with a description is much easier with a code. You just need a table of codes and descriptions, and then you write

```
select employee_name, event_code, date
from employee e
join employee_event ev on ev.employee_id=e.employee_id
join event v on v.event_id=ev.event_id
where ... whatever ...
```

But with the Booleans, you'd need a three-way case/when.

What happens when new event types are added? With an event code, it's just a data change: add a enw record to the event code table. With the Booleans, you need to change the database.

You create the potential for ambiguous data. What happens if two of the Booleans are true, or if none of them are true? What does that mean? There's a whole category of error that can't possibly happen with event codes.

Comment: Hi Jay, sorry for late response and thank you for detailed answer. Well in my case it is essential for me to allow more than one boolean to be true. So one date with one flag is not the solution. For better understandig: It's going to be a kind of check-in check-out with the ability to set an ok-date.

Comment: Is there a better solution than one of the tables above?

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood what you are trying to accomplish. I thought you were saying that the Booleans identify which of three possible dates it is.  If you're saying, On this date, which of these states are true? ... if all or most of the possible combinations are valid, then a set of Booleans is plausible. You still haven't said just what the flags mean, so the combinations are just arbitrary to me. What queries would you want to do? If you would commonly want to say, Which of these three things -- possibly more than one, maybe -- happened during March, a type code would still be superior ...

Comment: ... because it makes such queries simple. If the nature of the flags is that such a question would be meaningless, then maybe the Booleans isn't a bad idea. Like if we had a birth date and a hire date, it's very unlikely that anyone would ever ask, List all the employees born or hired last year. But if it's a hire date and a transferred to another department date, that's a plausible query. Etc.

Comment: Ok, well, imagine you want to enable this: check-out an item today. check the item finished tomorrow and check it in again also tomorrow or later. Or check it out, later check it in without finishing it.

Comment: To correct myself it even could be to check it out today, finish it today and check it in today.  So there should be a db query possible to list all items and show the current state by showing the last date of each of this three flags. E.g. saying: this item is checked-out, was last checked-in on [date] and was last finished on [date]

Answer (score 1):

Neither of those are normalized. Normalization is a good way to avoid data anomalies and keep things DRY.

What do your dates represent? What does "one", "two", and "three" represent?

I would go with something like this:

```
create table my_table (
  my_table_id int primary key,
  a_more_descriptive_word_than_date date not null,
  label text not null
);
```

The data would look like this:

```
id date       label
1  2014-12-23 one
2  2014-12-24 two
3  2014-12-25 three
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Late Answer from me: in your example it is not possible to have more than one label beeing assigned to the date

Comment: Or do you think I should make two entries instead of one?